# simplexml get value not all attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i am not very familiar with php (just start learning) and i have a problem:
i have a xml file on a server (from eve ... but who cares) and i managed it to "read" this file. it has a structure like this:

```
<result>
     <rowset>
          <row name="abc" id="def" ...>
          <row name="abc" id="def" ...>
          <row name="abc" id="def" ...>
          ...
     </rowset>
</result>
```

searching some web pages i found a way to echo all attributes of all rows.
here is my code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://api.eveonline.com/eve/AllianceList.xml.aspx?version=1";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$nrOfRows = $xml->result[0]->rowset[0]->count();
$n = 0;

for ($n = 0; $n <= $nrOfRows; $n++) {
    foreach($xml->result[0]->rowset[0]->row[$n]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        echo $a, " = ", $b, "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

as a result i get:

```
name = abc
id = def
...
name = abc
id = def
...
```

this looks nice but thats not exactly what i want.
i only need a special attribute of all rows. for example i want all the names of all rows as result.

thanks for any help.
sariel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array syntax to access to a single attribute:

```
echo $xml->result[0]->rowset[0]->row[$n]['name'];
```

will output:

```
Goonswarm Federation
Pandemic Horde
Test Alliance Please Ignore
(...)
```

Also note that you can simplify your code in this way:

```
foreach( $xml->result[0]->rowset[0]->row as $row )
{
    echo $row['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: big thanks! the "echo $xml->result[0]->rowset[0]->row[$n]['name'];" is exaktly what i was looking for :) and simplifying the loop is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses the build in [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)  and [DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) classes

```
$xml = <<< LOL
<result>
     <rowset>
          <row name="abc" id="def" lang="pt">Olá</row>
          <row name="abc" id="def" lang="en">Hello</row>
          <row name="abc" id="def" lang="fr">Bonjour</row>
     </rowset>
</result>
LOL;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//row") as $row){
    echo $row->getAttribute('name');
    echo $row->getAttribute('id');
    echo $row->getAttribute('lang');
    echo $row->textContent;
}
```

---

The above example will get the `name`, `id`,`lang` attributes and the text `text` of every row element.

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/5FA4zv)

---

If you need to filter the rows by `id` or `class`, use;

```
$xpath->query("//row[@class='someClass']")
$xpath->query("//row[@id='someId']")
```